# Using Ubuntu and Samba 4 (AD DC)

Tags: server, samba, active-directory

I'm using Ubuntu server to deploy an Active Directory Domain as our office is only small so it wouldn't make sense to purchase a copy of Server 2012 R2 or the like.

I've got everything set up and our Windows clients can see the Domain Controller but after I've rebooted the server, I can't get samba to start. The error I get is "Unknown enumerated value 'acive directory domain controller' for 'server role'" The quoted text is EXACTLY what the error says (including the 'active' misspelling). Does anybody know how I can fix this error to get samba back up and running?

Thanks in advance,

Ethan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the default install paths that come with `apt-get install samba` then go open the config file

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

And look for the line

```
  server role = active directory domain controller
```

Make sure that "active" is correctly spelled in this file, then restart the samba services

```
sudo service smbd restart
sudo service nmbd restart
sudo service winbindd restart
```

That should fix your issue